# Динамические картинки для шеринга в facebook

Tags: php, битрикс, facebook

Вечер, коллеги. Стоит на проекте такая задача

Выводится рандомная картинка, снизу есть кнопка "поделиться" (фб, вк, ок, телега и цап).

При шеринге в вк и ок, все идет замечательно.

При в фб и телегу, картинки не соответствуют тем, что на странице.
Уже пробовал манипуляции с URL, но ведь картинки выводятся рандомно, поэтому при первом скрапинге боту попадется тоже рандомная и она не та, что на странице.

Подскажите, как правильно реализовать задуманное?

Использую яндекс шеринг.

Ниже основной код:

```
$strURL = "<meta property='og:url' content= 'https://ломаябарьеры.рф/" . $url . "?&scrape=true" . "'>";
$strTitle = "<meta property='og:title' content='".$arResult["PROPERTIES"]["TEXT_REPOST"]["VALUE"]."'>";
$strImg = "<meta property='og:image' content= 'https://xn--80aacr0agnub4ii6a.xn--p1ai" . $src . "'>";

    

<div class="ya-share2 yShare"
        data-services="facebook,telegram,whatsapp"
        data-url:facebook="https://ломаябарьеры.рф/<?=$url . "?&scrape=true"?>"
        data-image:facebook="https://xn--80aacr0agnub4ii6a.xn--p1ai<?=$src?>"
        data-title:facebook="<?=$arResult["PROPERTIES"]["TEXT_REPOST"]["VALUE"]?>"
        ></div>
```

Comment: Фейсбук берёт данные из og метатегов, вы должны, когда шарите, посылать в фейсбук урл с каким то параметром (например ?post=123). Затем, бекендом вашего сайта нужно проверить есть ли этот параметр например в $_GET['post'], и в og метатеги подставить данные именно поста 123. Т.е. если у вас рандом и вы шарите то нужно передать ссылку на картинку где уже не будет рандома, а всегда одна картинка (определённый пост), которую шарили.

Comment: @ssv32, отлично, так и сделал, благодарю